# Work items sorted by completion date

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

In Visual Studio I'd like to create a work item query that list recently completed work items.

Apparently; when a Task is completed the "Closed Date" field is set, but when a Bug, Feature or User Story is completed then the "Resolved Date" is set instead.

[image: not a good solution]

In lack of a common "Completed Date" field, what I'd want is to sort by "Closed Date" or "Resolved Date", which ever is not empty.

Is something like this possible, or do I have to have two queries (one for Tasks and one for everything else)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug features and user stories also have a closed state that should cause closed date to be set.

See the guidance here for more info on the work item workflows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/guidance/agile-process-workflow

Comment: Really? All our closed bugs have the "Resolved" state and no "Closed Date" is set on them.

Comment: Oh crap. We've not been registering that verification part in TFS. :-(